# Display text from text file formated as html?

Tags: javascript, ajax

How can I display the text from **content.txt** and the tags in it to be displayed as regular html?

Comment: Get the content of the file using `XMLHttpRequest` and insert it inside a container using `.innerHTML`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, you create the file **content.txt** and you write in it your html source you want to be displayed. Example:
**content.txt**

```
Yep, this is the content.txt!
Some html?
<code>This is the code tag</code>
<button class="btn btn-primary" onclick="hideAjax()">Hide content.txt</button>
<h1>It works!</h1>
```

**HTML**

```
<div id="ajaxResponse">
    content.txt isn't displayed
</div>
    <button type="button" onclick="loadAjax()" class="btn btn-primary">Show text from content.txt</button>
```

**JS/Ajax**

```
 function loadAjax() {
   var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
   xhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
     if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
       document.getElementById("ajaxResponse").innerHTML =
       this.responseText;
     }
   };
   xhttp.open("GET", "content.txt", true);
   xhttp.send();
 }
```

**Note:** I've found this in [testingc.ga](https://www.tc.gamingprouk.net/#ajaxSection), so be sure to check out their version.